# Automatic creation record after save

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I replicate data of `tbl1` in `tbl2` after save?

Structure

```
Tbl1. Customer
id | first_name | last_name | address

Tbl2. Address
id | customer_id | address
```

Comment: I'd rather urge you to identify the relation between Customer and Address. (if you can identify one). Customer has_one adress or has_many ? And then save the related Address object via nested attributes. This approach might help you in the future.

Comment: I used "has_many" I think it is correct...

Answer (score 0):

If you use has_many

```
class Customer
  has_many :addresses

  after_save :create_address


  private
  def create_address
    self.addresses.create(address: self.address)
  end
end
```